# How to edit bluej launch script in Ubuntu14.04?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

I am trying to run bluej  using command terminal but I get this : 
A suitable Jdk couldn't be located. You may need to edit the /usr/bin/bluej launch script

Please help i am new to this.

Comment: Bluej is trying to find you jdk in your environmental path.

Comment: Does `echo $PATH | grep java` or `echo $PATH | grep jdk` return any thing ?

Comment: Yes it returns /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/sbin/:/usr/bin/:/sbib/:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/alka/bin:/home/maverick/jdk1.7.0_75//bin:/usr/local/jdk1.80_121/bin

Comment: After adding the `JAVA_HOME` any improvements ?

Comment: Nothing no improvement

Comment: Where is your java jvm installation?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't installed a JDK, you have several options.

### 1. APT and the official repositories

You may install one via apt-get, for that, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get openjdk-8-jdk
```

I recommend this, as it will set everything for you properly and you will be able to upgrade easily.

### 2. APT and the WebUpd8 PPA

You can also install Oracle's JDK vida the WebUpd8 PPA as [detailed here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre/56119#answer-61873), I believe it will also take care of everything for you.

### 3. Download directly from Oracle

Finally, you can install Oracle's JDK, but you will need to set set your JAVA_HOME, PATH and alternatives manually.

JAVA_HOME is used by some applications to find your JDK. I'm unsure if BlueJ uses it.

PATH is used by your shell session to know where it can look for any executables.

If you have several JDK versions, lets say you have the OpenJDK from the official Ubuntu repos, plus Oracle's JDK 1.8., both in your PATH. If you call javac, The Debian alternatives system will be used to resolve which one of those javac binaries will be used.

To do this, append this lines to your ~/.bashrc:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Source your bashrc file ( . ~/.bashrc ). Afterwards, update your alternatives (you will only need to do so if you have more than one JDK installed).

```
--install
  E.g. sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac 1

--set
  E.g. sudo update-alternatives --set javac $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac
```

To help you identify which alternatives you may need to update you can use:

```
update-alternatives --get-selections | grep java
```

---

If you really need to edit the launcher, you can edit /usr/share/applications/bluej.desktop:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/bluej.desktop
```

or add your own at

```
~/.local/share/applications/bluej.desktop
```

But I doubt that is the issue.

Comment: I have set the JAVA_HOME  and my current java version is " 1.8.0_121"

Comment: If you have installed a JDK and set all the variables/alternatives correctly BlueJ should launch without problems.

Comment: My problem has been sorted. I accidently  deleted  `/usr/lib/jvm`  then I resinstalled it using     `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer` and it worked well!!   Thank you everyone for your help :)

Comment: Good! You can post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been sorted. I accidently deleted `/usr/lib/jvm` then I reinstalled it using:

`sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

and it worked well!! Thank you everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

*first remove blueJ* 
`sudo apt remove bluej`
Install openjdk-8
`sudo apt-get openjdk-8-jdk`
Then Install Bluej .deb file
`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

It will be work